# RSA timing attack

Tags: rsa, timing-attack, montgomery-multiplication

1. Given an RSA implementation that uses Montgomery multiplications and CIOS exp algo, but NOT CRT.
2. Given a decryption1 oracle that takes chosen cipher text and responds the plain text and the time it took to decrypt it.
3. Given a decryption2 oracle that takes N,d,c and uses the same code as decryption1 oracle, it responds the time again it took to decrypt it and the plain text.

Can you please point me out on how I can implement an actual timing attack on this?